# CSS Stylesheet not showing styles

Tags: css

I'm currently designing this website http://avs.mybigcommerce.com. The problem is that my styles.css isn't showing any of its styles. Could somebody help me out?

here is a link to a screenshot
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46754431/store-screen.png

Comment: Im not sure but it seems that your second stylesheet has a css reset included. Try giving it as the first one.

Comment: http://avs.mybigcommerce.com/templates/__custom/Styles/styles.css?fc3ff http://avs.mybigcommerce.com/templates/__custom/Styles/red.css?fc3ff are my stylesheets. the red.css is working currently but not the styles.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you could check:

Check that you have correctly linked it:

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
     href="styles.css" title="Default Styles" media="screen">
```

- check that it the stylesheet is in the correct directory, etc.
- check that you have correct CSS and HTML markup. You could use tools such as http://validator.w3.org/ and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/
- make sure you clear the browser cache
- make sure that HTML is not within your CSS.

Further reference can be found here:

- http://csscreator.com/node/34253
- http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/199904.html

Comment: It is correctly linked...I will have to go through the validation sometime tonight and I will get back to it

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm it seems that Your stylesheet __master/Styles/styles.css comes before __custom/Styles/styles.css?fc3ff which has a css reset. (resets all values). Try changing the order of your stylesheets or include the reset as a seperate stylesheet which should come first. Hope this helps.